# tikz: how not to draw border of a shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this example to draw a circle:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=red](0, 0)circle(1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

How not to draw the border of this circle?

Comment: `\path[fill=red](0, 0)circle(1cm);` would also do but nowadays one should use the syntax `\path[fill=red](0, 0)circle[radius=1cm];` even though `circle(1cm)` will continue to work indefinitely (I hope).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `draw=none` you remove the draw color:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=red,draw=none](0, 0)circle(1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or more simply, using just `\fill` instead of `\draw`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[red](0, 0)circle(1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```